# a little help with NHibernate mapping over legacy database?

Tags: nhibernate

I am re-writing an app that sits over a legacy database. I'm using NHibernate and I've had problems getting some mappings to work and would like some help.

First, the table structure:

```
Tech:
Id
FirstName
LastName

User:
TechID
Username
```

The "User" table has no primary key. Foreign keys are no enforced at all. TechId is support to correspond to the Id on the Tech table.

My classes in memory are:

```
Tech:
Id 
FirstName
LastName
User (type: User)

User:
Id
Username
```

The tables and objects will always be 1-1.

At first I tried a HasOne relationship in the mappings but everytime it tried to save it did an update instead of an insert and when creating a new record I would get the infamous "update count expect: 1, actual:0 " type message.

I am also fine with changing my model so the Username is directly on the Tech but I can't get that mapping to work either.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well don't I feel silly. Some searching of the docs and I found the JOIN config. I collapsed the Username property onto the Tech and done.